# How to select multiple list items in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview

[How to select multiple list item in Android?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KuNV.png)

Which code do I use? If this code is right then what is next?

Comment: use checkbox.. then do whatever you want..

Comment: @ZeroOne is there any solution to without using checkbox i can select multiple items ?

Comment: See the example in this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: duplicate - see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369913/how-to-implement-multi-select-in-recyclerview

Comment: @ZeroOne its not work for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Multiple select adapter in list view you can find many library 
like [ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter)