# Implementing multi selection in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, gridlayoutmanager

I need some help with Multi/Single selection. Found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551984/5482999), because of its simplicity.
I'm using a `GridLayoutManager` I have over 90 items in my adapter, a `CardView` with a `TextView` and an `ImageView`, while using the procedure described in [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551984/5482999).

When I select one, or more than one item, as I scroll down, other items "seems" to be selected because the background replicates, but they are not selected.
Tried placing the `setOnClickListener`, in `onBindViewHolder` and also in MyViewHolder class and in both of them I get the same behaviour. When scrolling down other items seems to be selected.
Used `notifyItemChanged(position)` and `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter, but the background does not change at all, although the `setSelected` works properly.
Also I used `setHasFixedSize(true)` in the RecyclerView setup.

In `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {

    PatternImages currentPattern = patternImages.get(position);
    myViewHolder.setData(currentPattern, position);
    myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.setSelected(!v.isSelected());
            if (v.isSelected()) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryHighLight));

            } else {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Model

```
public class PatternImages {

    private int imageId, imageName;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public PatternImages(int imageId, int imageName, boolean isSelected) {

        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.imageName = imageName;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
    public int getImageId() {

        return imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {

        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public int getImageName() {

        return imageName;
    }
    public void setImageName(int imageName) {

        this.imageName = imageName;
    }
    public boolean isSelected() {

        return isSelected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {

        isSelected = selected;
    }
```

RecyclerView Setup

```
 private void setUpPatternsRecyclerView() {

    RecyclerView recyclerPatternsView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.pattern_image_recycler_view);
    PatternImageAdapter adapter = new PatternImageAdapter(this, patternImages);
    recyclerPatternsView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ColumnQty columnQty = new ColumnQty(this, R.layout.item_image_pattern_cardview);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), columnQty.calculateNoOfColumns());
    recyclerPatternsView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerPatternsView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerPatternsView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerPatternsView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacing(columnQty.calculateSpacing()));

}
```

setData Method

```
public void setData(PatternImages currentPattern, int position) {

    this.position = position;
    patternName.setText(context.getString(currentPattern.getImageName()));
    patternName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ElMessiri-SemiBold.ttf"));
    patternImage.setBackgroundResource(currentPattern.getImageId());
    if (position == 0 || position == 1) {
        animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) patternImage.getBackground();
        animationDrawable.start();
    }


}
```

Comment: put the code first

Comment: @ Avinash Roy, Done

Comment: For Kotlin users, the following article might be useful [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `RecyclerView` as its name suggests, recycles views. That means that once a view scrolls off screen, it can be reused.

Before a view is reused, it still contains all of the settings from the last time it was used. For example, if it contains a `TextView`, that `TextView` will still have its Text property set to whatever it was the last time it was displayed.

The reason that some items "seem" to be selected is because your selected views that have scrolled off screen are now being reused and you have not unselected them.

In your `OnBindViewHolder` method, you need to "reset" all the views back to their defaults. In this case that would be to "turn off" whatever method you use to make a view appear selected.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {

    final PatternImages currentPattern = patternImages.get(position);

    myViewHolder.setData(currentPattern, position);
    myViewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(currentPattern.isSelected() ?R.color.Red: R.color.WHITE); // choose your colors

    myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentPattern.setSelected(!currentPattern.isSelected())
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Essentially, every time you bind, you set the background colour to the selected or non selected state based on the relevant property in your model.

Comment: I added my `setData` method to the post and included the  5th line you provided in your code.
I might be wrong, but in the code you provided in the `onClick`, my pattern won't change the background, I believe(I'm rookie).
Now is working thanks to your comments, note that it works with or without the `notifyItemChanged(position)`.
For what I understand my error was not to provide a background initially to the view, as the view's background was already white(tried with `Color.RED` and `Color.BLUE` for testing)

Comment: Yes the code above will change the background. That is what NotifyItemChanged does. It caused the OnBindViewHolder to be called again for the relevant position which then in turn sets the background color of the container view.

Comment: You are totally right, thank you for your time.
I had a week trying to figure this out.

Comment: Additionally, I would move some code from `setData` to the `OnCreateViewHolder` method.  For example, you are setting the typeface of your `TextView` every time you bind data. You only need to do that once when the view is created as it never changes. Not very efficient to do it repeatedly when is is not needed. You are slowing the process down unnecessarily.

Comment: Wow, that's a great bonus, Thank You!!

Answer (score 2):

recently, i had worked on recyclerview multi selection, so you could try this first initialize sparseboolean, boolean an one int like this :

```
private SparseBooleanArray storeChecked = new SparseBooleanArray();
private boolean isMultiselect;
private int itemSelected;
```

so on bindViewHolder, add this

```
holder.view.setbackground(storechecked.get(position) ? Color.White : Color.Black)
```

then,
implement onLongClickListener.
on longClick
add this:

```
if(!ismultiSelect){
  storechecked.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
  notifyDataSetChanged(getAdapterPosition());
  triggerOnLongClickListener(++itemSelected); // using listerner i've transfer position to fragment for actionmode selected count

}
```

after this, in onClick do this:

```
if(ismultiSelect){
   boolean tof = storechecked.get(getAdapterPosition());
           if (tof){
                triggerOnItemClickListener(--itemSelected, v); // transfer position to update unselected 
                storeChecked.delete(position);// delete position of unselected position in the fragment
            }else {
                triggerOnItemClickListener(++itemSelected, v);
             // transfer position to update selected  position in the fragment
        }
    } 

 **Other methods in adapter**

   //clear on actionmode close
   public void exitMultiselectMode() {
    isMultiselect = false;
    itemSelected = 0;
    storeChecked.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

   // get all selected position
   public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
     List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>(storeChecked.size());
     for (int i = 0; i < storeChecked.size(); ++i) {
         items.add(storeChecked.keyAt(i));
     }
     return items;
  }
```

Comment: This is better answer than original

Comment: @VygintasB i've updated code and some fixes will help to get working multi selection in recyclerview, let me know if any other issue faced :) ps: previous i was typing on stackoverflow app due to some code and explaination was missing .

Answer (score 2):

Try to keep the state in model but in view, and bind the model to view in `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Kuffs solution and I'm posting my final code for reference.

onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {

    final PatternImages currentPattern = patternImages.get(position);
    myViewHolder.setData(currentPattern, position);
    myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            currentPattern.setSelected(!currentPattern.isSelected());

            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });

}
```

`setData()` Method

```
public void setData(PatternImages currentPattern, int position) {

    this.position = position;
    patternName.setText(context.getString(currentPattern.getImageName()));
    patternName.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ElMessiri-SemiBold.ttf"));
    patternImage.setBackgroundResource(currentPattern.getImageId());
    if (position == 0 || position == 1) {
        animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) patternImage.getBackground();
        animationDrawable.start();
    }
    itemView.setBackgroundColor(currentPattern.isSelected() ? ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryHighLight) : Color.WHITE);
}
```