# RecyclerView with multiple onclick events on textviews

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview

I want to build a RecyclerView with a few columns within each row that should be clickable to different events. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to determine which onclick is being clicked within the row, as they all call the same method. What's the best way to handle this? Should I declare multiple views within the row and assign an onclick to each View?

Here is my recyclerview.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="Description"
            android:id="@+id/description_textview"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="99"
            android:id="@+id/qty_textview"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/description_textview"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="N"
            android:id="@+id/accept_textview"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/qty_textview"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGray"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my recyclerview holder code (normal recyclerview). I want to replace the onLongClick event with a different column:

```
private class RecyclerHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
    private TextView descriptionTextView;
    private TextView qtyTextView;
    private TextView acceptTextView;
    private VerificationModel verificationModel;

    public RecyclerHolder2(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        descriptionTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_textview);
        qtyTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.qty_textview);
        acceptTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept_textview);
    }

    public void bindRecyclerData(VerificationModel newItem) {
        verificationModel = newItem;
        descriptionTextView.setText(verificationModel.getDescription());
        qtyTextView.setText(verificationModel.getQty());
        acceptTextView.setText(verificationModel.getAccept());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean accepted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < mVerifys.size(); i++) {
            if (mVerifys.get(i).equals(verificationModel)) {
                if (mVerifys.get(i).getAccept().equals("N")) {
                    mVerifys.get(i).setAccept("Y");
                    mVerifys.get(i).setSelected(true);
                    Timber.d(verificationModel.getDescription() + " was accepted");
                } else {
                    mVerifys.get(i).setAccept("N");
                    mVerifys.get(i).setSelected(false);
                    Timber.d(verificationModel.getDescription() + " was unaccepted");
                }
            }
            if (mVerifys.get(i).getAccept().equals("N")) {
                accepted = false;
            }
        }
        mRecyclerAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (accepted) {
            mAcceptedButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick (View v) {
        Timber.d(verificationModel.getDescription() + " will be adjusted");
        Intent intent = new Intent(VerificationDetailActivity.this, InvoiceAuthorizationActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good way to solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369913/how-to-implement-multi-select-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you're setting your listeners like this:

```
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
```

There are two different ways you can achieve what you're looking for.

The first is to use the same `View.OnClickListener` for each view, and then change what you do based on the clicked view's ID.

```
public RecyclerHolder2(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ...
    descriptionTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    descriptionTextView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    qtyTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    qtyTextView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    acceptTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    acceptTextView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.description_textview) {
        ...
    }
    else if (...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The second (and the one I recommend) is to use a different `View.OnClickListener()` for each view. This will cause you to write a little more code, but makes it more obvious that different clicks do different things. (And if you're using RetroLambda you can wind up omitting most of the boilerplate).

```
private View.OnClickListener descriptionListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener quantityListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ...
    }
};

public RecyclerHolder2(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ...
    descriptionTextView.setOnClickListener(descriptionListener);
    qtyTextView.setOnClickListener(quantityListener);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getAdapterPosition()` from your `ViewHolder`, which returns the position of the item in the `RecyclerView`. And using that position you can find which row has been clicked.

The position that is being returned is the position based on the total items in the `RecyclerView` and not just the items that are visible on the screen.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear.  I already have an event that responds to which row is clicked.  I want to respond to which COLUMN has been clicked.

Comment: Instead of setting the `clickListener` to the `itemView`, you should set it to individual `view` (or column).

Answer (score 0):

You sould listen at your wanted `TextView`. Using `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);` you listen to entire item of adapter. You should use `acceptTextView.setOnClickListener(this);` because you want to listen to specific view and in `onClick()` method check for clicked item.

```
switch(view.getId()) {
   case R.id.accept_textview:
       // do what you want when click accept textview
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most clean way to handle click events is to use Butterknife library and have a separate method for all clicks. It removes so much boilerplate code and really easy to work with. See how to use Butterknife here - http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Another way is to provide different onClick methods for each TextView. Like this

```
android:onClick="textButton1Clicked"
```

Another approach is to get the ID of the TextViews in the onclick and see which on the user clicked

```
 if (view.getID() == R.id.textView1) {

} else (view.getID() == R.id.textView2) {

} else (view.getID() == R.id.textView3) {

}
```

You can also use a switch statement for better maintainability.