# Select ReyclerView item(just single tap) with recycler view selection library

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I new to **RecyclerView Selection library**. I prepared `RecyclerView` to select multiple item just single tap. My problem is that all of the article and tutorial show that selection process start with long press.

How can i overwrite to start selection with single tap? Thanks.

I'm using `implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.0.0'`

The tutorial,I tried..

- https://github.com/guenodz/recyclerview-selection-demo
- https://medium.com/@Dalvin/android-recycler-view-with-multiple-item-selections-b2af90eb5825
- http://androidkt.com/recyclerview-selection-28-0-0/
- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-selection-support-to-a-recyclerview--cms-32175

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551984/7319704

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After digging over weeks, I found working solution.
According to **한로니**

> If you want single-tap to select, just override `inSelectionHotspot(e:
>   MotionEvent)` to return `true`

```
object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
        override fun getSelectionKey(): Long? {

            return itemId
        }

        override fun getPosition(): Int {
            return adapterPosition
        }

        override fun inSelectionHotspot(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return true
        }
```

For more u can see on [Here](https://medium.com/p/7316c3c8eb44/info)

Comment: What about disabling the long click? meaning using it for a different action?

Comment: please explain a little bit more.

Comment: Sure, What I want is the option to enable selection with a single click, and do another operation like open the image in a long click, just like Google Files app does.

Comment: How do I customize `inSelectionHotspot` so that only a checkbox is the only selectable region and work with single click?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is you need to use below code to implement.

```
  recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
              // Add your selection code here...
            }
        }));
```

Below is RecyclerItemClickListener class.

```
package com.android.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

This is custom onItemClickListener for RecyclerView.

Comment: I'm so Sorry, @Nitish, coz.you may misunderstand on something. My topic is about  [ReyclerViewSelection](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/package-summary). Thank you!

Comment: Ohh! Sorry, I will look into it when get a chance and you can use above also, in case if you want to do it directly (Without ReyclerViewSelection). Thanks