# How to highlight item of recyclerView after long press like Telegram?

Tags: java, android

If you know in Telegram to delete chat or group we hold item(long press) and clicking another item then we add the group to chat, to delete the list, I cant do it.

Currently I can listening just only click like this:

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"Short Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and listening long click:

```
 itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(),"Short Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In my case, I want to listen to long-press and then I want to highlight item(of course, the item is part of recyclerView) with just click(not long click) I googled but it did not help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement multi-select in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369913/how-to-implement-multi-select-in-recyclerview)

Comment: in this case There are using item click (short click), I can do it, in my case I have to use first long click and then highlight another item with click(not long)

Comment: In your OnLongClickListener you can iterate through recyclerView items ant set new OnClickListener to select them. Also, you need to store some flag to switch behaviour in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: @Bracadabra thanks a lot ! I solved this question like in your case...

Comment: Cool, glad to help, then I will move the comment to answers not to leave the question open.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest solution is the following:

1. In OnLongClickListener iterate through RecyclerView views and set new OnClickListener to handle selection.
2. Store some flag to switch behavior in onBindViewHolder.