# Multiselect recycle view but with contact list

Tags: android, android-studio

Iam trying to make a multi select list for contacts , i followed this here first answer [How to implement multi-select in RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369913/how-to-implement-multi-select-in-recyclerview/40551984#40551984)

But it only shows how to make it for text view , can anyone please help making it import and show contacts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace textView with your view in that answer. and top of that you did not provide any code of layout or adapter, so how anyone could understand your problem completely? Add some code to your question brother.